# How can models get exactly the same accuracy on randomised data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am comparing models for a genetics classification, they are classifiying between 4 classes for genes to be certainly, possibly, likely or unknown in relation to affecting a disease.

I run these and they all get around 65-80% accuracy, this is with nested cross validation to avoid overfitting to get these percentages. But I then give these models a randomised dataset, and some of the models are managing to get the exact same accuracy with multiple runs (with no cross validation and just seeing accuract with split test data), is this really possible or is it that these models are reaching a plateau? From my beginner point of view I would have assume it unlikely, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code for testing on randomise data:

```
inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

models = []
models.append(('LR', dcv.GridSearchCV(logreg, LR_par, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=-1)))
models.append(('SVM', dcv.GridSearchCV(svm, tuned_parameters, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=-1)))
models.append(('RFC', dcv.GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=-1)))
models.append(('Keras', GridSearchCV(estimator=keras, param_grid=kerasparams, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=-1)))

arr = np.arange(5400).reshape((600, 9))
random = np.random.permutation(arr)
ran = np.random.randint(4, size=600)
rand = np.column_stack((random, ran))
print(rand.shape)
X1 = rand[0:600,0:8]
Y1 = rand[0:600,-1]
print("Random data counts of label '0': {}".format(sum(ran==0)))
print("Random data counts of label '1': {}".format(sum(ran==1)))
print("Random data counts of label '2': {}".format(sum(ran==2)))
print("Random data counts of label '3': {}".format(sum(ran==3)))
print(X1.shape)
print(Y1.shape)
X1 = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X1)

X_train1, X_test1, Y_train1, Y_test1 = train_test_split(X1, Y1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

for name, model in models:
    model.fit(X1, Y1)
    print(name, 'Random accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model.score(X_test1, Y_test1)*100),  '%')
```

Output looks like:

```
(600, 10)
Random data counts of label '0': 136
Random data counts of label '1': 153
Random data counts of label '2': 155
Random data counts of label '3': 156
(600, 8)
(600,)


LR Random accuracy: 26.67 %
SVM Random accuracy: 26.67 %
RFC Random accuracy: 38.33 %
Keras Random accuracy: 23.33 %
```

It seems to be something like, if I run this code 4 times, the first time the accuracies are different, the next 3 times they stay the same usually for SVM and LR (logistic regression).

I am using python 3.7 within anaconda and using Jupyterlab 0.35.4

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your problem lies in the way you use KFold from sklearn. As far as RFC (taking a guess as to Random Forest Classifier), it also has a random element. Logistic Regression also has a random factor to it, and SVM I don't know about. For what it's worth, here is some of the documentation. Before asking questions on stackoverflow, I would recommend looking up the documentation for each algorithm.

From the documentation for KFold:

> **shuffle : boolean, optional**
>
> Whether to shuffle the data before splitting into batches.
>
> **random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional,
>   default=None**
>
> If int, random_state is the seed used by the random
>   number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random
>   number generator; If None, the random number generator is the
>   RandomState instance used by np.random. Used when shuffle == True.

And Random Forest Classifier

> **bootstrap : boolean, optional (default=True)**
>
> Whether bootstrap samples are used when building trees. If False, the
>   whole datset is used to build each tree.

So if you want the exact same data every time, you should make shuffle false and remove random_state (because the default is None).

```
inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False)
```

Though this does not ensure that you get the same results, as that is very dependent on the algorithms you use. Random Forest and Logistic Regression from Scikit-Learn both have a random element that you cannot turn off, according to the documentation.